# Image upload sometime fails silently when upload is attempted quickly after loading the ask question page

Tags: bug, images, uploader

Demo (I loaded the  ask question page, pasted an image, hit "enter" and the image upload sometime silently failed):

[image]

This happened to me a few times (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate + Google Chrome Version 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

Comment: What happens if you click the “redo” button? It’s lit up.

Comment: What's with you and all the failed upload attempts?  I don't remember I ever had an image upload fail before. P.S. Don't get me wrong; I'm all for discovering bugs. I'm just wondering how you're getting all those upload failures.